# how to create a button to play an audio file

Tags: javascript, css, html, encoding

I would like create a button to play an audio file and style it to look like an arrow this is my attempt, but I don't know how to write the javascript part

HTML:

```html
 <div class="play">
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">
   <audio class="kskin" data-durationhint="1.55" data-startoffset="0" preload="none" style="width:175px">
    <source data-bandwidth="100377" data-height="0" data-shorttitle="Ogg source" data-title="Original Ogg file (100 kbps)" data-width="0" src="audio/giraalaizquierda.mp3" type='audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'>
   </audio>
  </button>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.play{
    background-image: url("../../img/play.svg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `id` attribut into `audio` tag

```
<audio id="player" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you were quite there.

The Javascript use for lauching the audio is on the button element, with:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()
```

you simply need to add the Id tag `<audio id="player">`